# How do you pronounce the publisher "Springer"?

Tags: pronunciation

From what I learned in my home country, we pronounce this publisher as **/əʃpəriːngɜːr/** which I guess it has something to do with German language.

I want to know if it's strange to say **/əʃpəriːngɜːr/**?

Comment: The commonly-heard pronunciation in the US - or at least in the NYC area - is any of /ʃpriːngɜːr/, /spriːngɜːr/, /ʃpriːngə/, /spriːngə/. The first is considered the most correct. The first vowel may shade into /ɪ/ in any case.

Comment: The first two schwas are odd: they're not there in English or German. I suspect they are artifacts of the phonotactics of your native language, which probably doesn't employ these consonant clusters at word onset.

Comment: In German the standard pronunciation is /ʃprɪŋɐ/, although no doubt there are various regional variations, some of which might retain the final /r/,  In English I would probably say either /sprɪŋə/ or /ʃprɪŋə/.

Comment: @StoneyB It was the only option that I had to convey how this word is pronounced in "Iran".

Comment: How is this about learning English?

Comment: @user3169 how about removing the tag?

Comment: Could you add some details on who "the publisher “Springer” is?

Comment: That's it, then: Wikipedia says that the Persian language has "an optional syllable onset, consisting of **one** consonant", so those you hear saying /əʃpəriːngɜːr/ are trying to accommodate the /spr/ cluster to Persian. There are actually at least three publishers named Springer: Springer-Verlag, a huge presence in academic texts, and Axel Springer SE, Europe's largest digital media publisher, both in German, and Springer Publishing Co. in the US, a publisher of medical and healthcare works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about German by its very terms.

Comment: @JeffMorrow For your information, that's a very famous English publisher, you can google it!

Comment: @Cardinal "something to do with the German language" is what is in the original message. Later you suggest that you are talking about Farsi. What does this have to do with learning English? If you want know how to pronounce in English the name of an English publisher, I suggest that you clarify your original question. Of course, there is a German publisher named "Springer," and you may want to know how English speakers pronounce that German name. Your question **as written** is off topic as well as vague.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Probably because I am no longer in my home country, and I had no idea what is the proper (idiomatic) pronunciation. My intention was to know if it's OK to pronounce it either ways.

Comment: @Cardinal I still think you should clarify your question. The name of an English or American company should normally be spoken according to the standard rules (such as they are) of English orthography. The name of a German company will be spoken in English variously: some will pronounce it according to German orthography and some according to English orthography. The less significant in international commerce is the company and the less knowledgeable a speaker is about the foreign language involved, the more likely the name is to anglicized.

Answer (score 1):

The pronunciation you have written is not how native speakers would say the word.

The common pronunciations are:

> /ʃpriːngɜːr/, /spriːngɜːr/, /ʃpriːngə/, or /spriːngə/